# Is there any solution to hide "refreshing..." message and animation on IOS simulator?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm beginner react-native developer.

is there any way to prevent appear blue screen and animation with message "refreshing..." in IOS simulator, when I write code?

I don't want to see that screen and message every time when I write code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz1pp.jpg)

ideally, I want to keep auto refreshing function, and just remove "refreshing..." message and screen.

thank you.

Comment: Hello @fluorjo this is not actually possible yet!! :)

Comment: hello. thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible follow my steps

open HMRClient.js from

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/HMRClient.js
```

Search this `LoadingView.showMessage('Refreshing...', 'refresh');`  and comment this

Comment: wow it works. I comment out code what you said.

`If (client.isEnabled() && !isInitialUpdate) {
// LoadingView.showMessage('Refreshing...', 'refresh');   <-here. 
} `

and really "refreshing..." screen disappeared.

I really thank you for your help ! 

I'm a bit afraid of seeing repetitive movements.
so I really needed your solution. 

thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome,  mark my question as answered  check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I checked it. sorry. I didn't know about it because this question is my first question. thank you.